# Applying a dictionary to a list to output a set

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary with 24 entries, it maps each number from 0 to 23 to a list:

```
{0: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4], 3: [5, 1, 3, 4, 2], 4: [5, 1, 4, 2, 3], 5: [5, 1, 4, 3, 2], 6: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4], 7: [5, 2, 1, 4, 3], 8: [5, 2, 3, 1, 4], 9: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1], 10: [5, 2, 4, 1, 3], 11: [5, 2, 4, 3, 1], 12: [5, 3, 1, 2, 4], 13: [5, 3, 1, 4, 2], 14: [5, 3, 2, 1, 4], 15: [5, 3, 2, 4, 1], 16: [5, 3, 4, 1, 2], 17: [5, 3, 4, 2, 1], 18: [5, 4, 1, 2, 3], 19: [5, 4, 1, 3, 2], 20: [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], 21: [5, 4, 2, 3, 1], 22: [5, 4, 3, 1, 2], 23: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
```

I then want to take a list with 24 0's and 1's looking something like:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and I want to then print out a set with just the lists in the dictionary that correspond to the indices that are 1's in the 24 long list of 0's and 1's

So in the above example it would return a set with just `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 1, 3, 2, 4]` in it.

The reason I'm trying to create a set of lists is so that I can later on apply a transformation on every list within a given set and see if after that transformation the set is equivalent to another set.

Comment: OK, so do you have any code that you tried so far then we could figure out what you mean exactly?

Comment: You can't have a set containing lists; will a list of lists suffice?

Comment: the problem is that order really doesn't matter and later on I need to see if these sets are equivalent. A list of lists wouldn't be terrible though.

Answer (score 1):

first, you can't hash lists, so instead of a set of lists, we'll have a set of tuples.

assuming that your dictionary is named `d` and your `0/1 list` is named `mask`, your result is simply:

```
res = set(tuple(d[i]) for i, v in enumerate(mask) if v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a set of lists, as they are unhashable. This is because they are mutable (can change). A close alternative would be a set of tuples. And you should remove duplicates in the input list as well.

```
mapping = {0: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4], 3: [5, 1, 3, 4, 2], 4: [5, 1, 4, 2, 3], 5: [5, 1, 4, 3, 2], 6: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4], 7: [5, 2, 1, 4, 3], 8: [5, 2, 3, 1, 4], 9: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1], 10: [5, 2, 4, 1, 3], 11: [5, 2, 4, 3, 1], 12: [5, 3, 1, 2, 4], 13: [5, 3, 1, 4, 2], 14: [5, 3, 2, 1, 4], 15: [5, 3, 2, 4, 1], 16: [5, 3, 4, 1, 2], 17: [5, 3, 4, 2, 1], 18: [5, 4, 1, 2, 3], 19: [5, 4, 1, 3, 2], 20: [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], 21: [5, 4, 2, 3, 1], 22: [5, 4, 3, 1, 2], 23: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
def get_set(l):
    return {tuple(mapping.get(ind)) for ind, adding in enumerate(l) if adding)}
```

Then, with your example:

```
>>> a = get_set([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> a
{(5, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 1, 2, 4, 3)}
```

Then, to do transformations to the tuples, remove them from the set, cast as a list, then put them back. An example (adding `7` to every element):

```
new_set = set()
for tup in iter(a):
    new_set.add(tuple(i + 1 for i in tup))
a = new_set
```

Comment: Why the `iter()` call? And the OP wanted to match *indices* from the input list; it's a boolean 'mask'.

Comment: This only works by fluke.  `set(l)` is giving you {0,1}, when really the OP wants `{0, 2}`.

Comment: So is there any way to have an set, or something where order doesn't matter, composed of things where order does matter and I can then transform each element such element within the set? Essentially what I'm hoping is if I have a set that contains only [1,2,3,4,5] and a different set that contains [5,1,2,3,4], then I could rotate every list within the second set left one and then they'd be the same set and I could eliminate one of the sets.

Answer (score 0):

Sets can not contain unhashable types. Specifically lists. It is common practice to use the immutable `tuple` type instead:

Create result set:

```
>>> result = set()
```

Define the mapping:

```
>>> mapping = {0: [5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4], 3: [5, 1, 3, 4, 2], 4: [5, 1, 4, 2, 3], 5: [5, 1, 4, 3, 2], 6: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4], 7: [5, 2, 1, 4, 3], 8: [5, 2, 3, 1, 4], 9: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1], 10: [5, 2, 4, 1, 3], 11: [5, 2, 4, 3, 1], 12: [5, 3, 1, 2, 4], 13: [5, 3, 1, 4, 2], 14: [5, 3, 2, 1, 4], 15: [5, 3, 2, 4, 1], 16: [5, 3, 4, 1, 2], 17: [5, 3, 4, 2, 1], 18: [5, 4, 1, 2, 3], 19: [5, 4, 1, 3, 2], 20: [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], 21: [5, 4, 2, 3, 1], 22: [5, 4, 3, 1, 2], 23: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
```

Define the "to add" list:

```
>>> test = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now iterate paired `(index, should_add)` items and add to result set when needed:

```
>>> for index, add_flag in enumerate(test):
...     if add_flag:
...         result.add(tuple(mapping[index]))
...
```

Result:

```
>>> result
set([(5, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 1, 3, 2, 4), (5, 4, 1, 3, 2)])
```

Note that I've added a `1` in `test`.

If you need a function that does it:

```
def mask_dict(mapping, mask):
    result = set()
    for index, should_add in enumerate(mask):
        if should_add:
            result.add(tuple(mapping[index]))
    return result
```

Comment: Secondary question. Let's say I've got two sets, 'set([(5, 1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 1, 3, 2, 4), (5, 4, 1, 3, 2)])' and 'set([(4, 1, 3, 2, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 3, 2, 4, 5)])' the second set being just the first with it's terms re-ordered and rotated left one. Is there any way to check a bunch of transformations on all the second set's elements and when it sees that the second set is just the first set rotated left one it does something. Essentially what I'm asking is if there's a way to transform every element within a set and then see if it's equivalent to other sets.

Comment: Oh I know how to apply the transformation I want on each list, I just don't know whether that's something I can do to tuples within a set.

Comment: you can't mutate tuples if that's what you're asking. It *seems* like you need advice about something higher then this specific issue (XY problem).